# PyMuPDF ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pymupdf

I successfully ran the command:

```
pip install pymupdf
Successfully installed pymupdf-1.18.15
```

However, both

```
import fitz
```

and `import pymupdf`

both output an
`ModuleNotFoundError`.

Why is python giving me a `ModuleNotFoundError`?

Comment: Try `pip install PyMuPDF`

Comment: the same error.

Answer (score 1):

1. According to [PyMuPDF
   Documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#option-2-install-from-binaries)
   you need to download a wheel file that is specific to your platform
   (e.g windows, mac, linux). The wheel files can be found on [PyMuPDF
   files](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/#files).
2. Make sure to check the correct version of your python running on
   your system `python -V`
3. Once downloaded place it at the root directory of your project.
4. Then run `pip install PyMuPDF-<...>.whl` replace `PyMuPDF-<...>.whl`
   with the name of the wheel file you have downloaded in (1) above.
5. Now `import fitz` should be available in your module.

Comment: It would be better to link to the current, official documentation, which, for [PyMuPDF](//pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/), is on pymupdf.readthedocs.io. The [current installation documentation](//pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) is different than what's shown on the docs page you've linked in this answer. That doesn't invalidate your statement that it's necessary to install the correct wheel. However, `pip` *should* automatically select and install the correct wheel for the current architecture, or build from source if none is found or the `--no-binary` option is used.

Comment: pip install PyMuPDF-<...>.whl throws this error.
ERROR: PyMuPDF-1.21.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. My laptop config : Windows 11 OS 16 GB RAM, with AMD Ryzen Radeon Graphics Card.  tried downloading most approrpiate .whl file, PyMuPDF-1.21.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl , but refuses to install.!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
pip install --upgrade pymupdf
```

This will install from a Python wheel if one is available for your platform

https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#option-2-install-from-binaries